# How to restrict login to already logged Users in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, access-control

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/logout, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/recover-password, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/activate-account, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

It seems that the access_control works fine for restricting access for different roles, but I need something like `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`*`only`*`&& ! ROLE_USER && ! ROLE_ADMIN`.

I don't want that as already logged in to allow accessing this route. If this is possible from `security.yml` it would be great.

Comment: From 2.4 onwards, you don't need `JMSSecurityExtraBundle` - Symfony added an [`ExpressionLanguage`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/expression/expressions.html#security-complex-access-controls-with-expressions) component, that allows you to secure a route with an expression using the [`allow_if` property](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html#securing-by-an-expression); e.g: `allow_if: 'is_anonymous()'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JMSSecurityExtraBundle` adds expression support.

Example from documentation:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/foo, access: "hasRole('FOO') and hasRole('BAR')" }
```

Further reading: [Expression-based Authorization Language](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/expressions)

Answer (score 9):

You can do exactly what you thought you could:

```
- { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICADED_FULLY }
```

Answer (score 3):

@drgomesp answer isn't correct. Since a non logged user is considered authenticated anonymously, and a fully authenticated user is also an anonymous user. 
Look this:

```
- { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICADED_FULLY }
```

This means, if I am authenticated anonymously and also not authenticated anonymously show "^/" url. It will lead to an infinite loop.

I've already answered this here, check the solution: https://creativcoders.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/symonfy2-restrict-login-access-to-already-logged-users/

```
- { path: /login$, access: "!isAuthenticated()" }
```

Base from official doc http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/expressions#usage-in-access-control